# Access custom variable without using IPN

Tags: html, paypal

Is it possible to get the value of the `custom` variable from without using IPN?

I have a very simple project that doesn't need auto payment verification or anything like that, everything is done manually. I just need to like one input from the payment page along with that payment.

So is it possible to get the info from the `custom` variable in the payment confirmation email from paypal or the paypal payment receipt?

Check out button example:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="paypal-form" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@email.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item Name">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="10.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" id="payment-custom" value="CUSTOM VALUE">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

So I want to get that "CUSTOM VALUE" without using a ipn script, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GetTransactionDetails API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) will return it

Comment: Andrew is correct; the CUSTOM field is assumed to be machine-readable/useful but not necessarily displayable/human-useful (people often put IDs or even compound keys in the CUSTOM field). So it won't show up in emails but can be retrieved via the getTransactionDetails API (as well as IPN or PDT). It also is returned in the post back to your site at the end of the transaction flow, so your web server could capture it there and do something with it (including emailing it to you, or putting it in some fulfillment queue you manage) if that helps. This does not require API integration.

Comment: See the section on "pass-through variables" in https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_websitepaymentsstandard_integrationguide.pdf if you want to process the CUSTOM field in your website when the user returns. Of course if you do this, make sure you set the PayPal button to return the user, and be aware that if their internet drops (or they close the browser or something) they might pay and then not return. Rare, but it can happen.